# Show and Hide element from Script and/or from Razor Model View with MVC

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an element in a Razor View:

```
<div class="label">When? *</div>
```

That I need to show in a View based on a ModeView condition:

```
<div id="label" class="label" style="@(Model.SearchedServiceId == 14 ? "display:block" : "")">When? *</div>
```

But I need to be able to hide it from jQuery:

```
$("#label").fadeOut();
```

And I define the style like:

```
.label {
    display: none;
}
```

The problem is that when the condition is true in the element, and the display:block is added to the element, I am unable to hide it from jQuery:

```
$("#label").fadeOut();
```

is not hiding the element.

Comment: did you try hide()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
Model.SearchedServiceId = 14
```

```js
//var a = @Html.Raw(Model.SearchedServiceId); //you can add your Model.SearchedServiceId
var a = 14;
if(a == 14)
{
  $( "#book" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}
else
{
  $( "#book" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="book" class="label-block" style="display:block">adsada</label>

<style>
.label-block{
  display:none;
}

</style>
```

```
Model.SearchedServiceId = 15
```

```js
//var a = @Html.Raw(Model.SearchedServiceId); //you can add your Model.SearchedServiceId
var a = 15;
if(a == 14)
{
  $( "#book" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}
else
{
  $( "#book" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="book" class="label-block" style="display:block">adsada</label>

<style>
.label-block{
  display:none;
}

</style>
```

Comment: What I need to achieve is the ability to hide an element that has been set as visible in the Views' load

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146173/discussion-between-hasan-and-patrick).

Answer (score 2):

By using style

```
style="@(Model.SearchedServiceId == 14 ? "display:block" : "")"
```

you override all classes since inline style is more powerful than css classes ids etc.
Instead of applying following code to style echo it in class as follows

```
class="@(Model.SearchedServiceId == 14 ? "superClass" : "")"
```

then in your css file define what super class is

```
.superClass{
  display:block;
}
```

by this way you wont need to override with important thus you can use fadeOut without problem.

If displaying it as block still causes problem you can use `.removeClass('superClass');` before you fade out

Comment: Updated according to your response

Comment: If I check the flag at the page load, the FadeIn effect is visible to the user when the View is loaded and it can't be, it has to be already there in the page if service = 14.

Comment: why you cannot use .show() then there will be no fadeIn and you ll get a reversable display block which will work with fadeout

Comment: because the show is visible to the user after the View's load and if it's displayed using @() it's not visible

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out that I had an issue in my code that was preventing the element from being hidded. I like your solution, I check hasan's answer as correct because he gave also a correct answer, but sooner. Thanks again

Comment: @Patrick this answer better than mine, please accept this answer instead of mine